# Forward class properties Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

i am making an Mac OS X application and i'm trying to let classes know of each other

Controller creates View1 and View2

BaseView has a property of Controller

View1 and View2 extends from BaseView

here is my example

Controller Class

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "View1.h"
@class View1;
@interface Controller : NSViewController
{
    View1 *_view1;
}
@end

//////

#import "Controller.h"

@implementation Controller

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self )
    {
        _view1 = [[View1 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _view1.controller = self;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

BaseView Class

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Controller.h"
@class Controller;
@interface BaseView : NSView
{
    Controller *_controller;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) Controller *controller;

@end

//////

#import "BaseView.h"

@implementation BaseView

@synthesize controller = _controller;

@end
```

View Example Class

```
#import "BaseView.h"

@interface View1 : BaseView

@end

//////

#import "View1.h"

@implementation View1

@end
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Controller.m:23:16: Property 'controller' cannot be found in forward class object 'View1'
```

what do i do wrong?

Comment: Once you do the import, you dont need to do the @class Controller directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a forward declaration in your header file(e.g. `@class View1;`), you do not need to `#import` the header.

In your View1.h you don't declare a @class, that's where you get the error. Nevertheless I suggest you to use forward declaration in your header file and import the needed headers in your implementation file when you need the method declarations etc. - this will prevent you from a header loop, too.

your code should look like

```
@class BaseView; 
@interface View1 : BaseView

@end  

////// 

#import "View1.h"
#import "BaseView.h"
@implementation View1  

@end
```

Comment: ok i change that but when i want to do: _view1.controller = self in my Controller class i get this error: Property 'controller' cannot be found in forward class object 'View1'

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might not be in your code.

Are they in the same relative folder? Is `BaseView` in a different location? You might have to go to your project settings and adjust your `User Header Search Paths` if this is the case

Also, make sure that all of your files are set up for the target you are currently running, by clicking on them on the project navigator, and in the right-hand side menu check which targets it's marked

Comment: they are all in the same folder and all are added to the target, i don't think its a problem with that?